# Makefile: return first two characters of a string

Tags: string, parsing, makefile

Given a string in a Makefile, is it possible to extract the first two characters of an unknown string using Makefile syntax (without using shell calls)?

for instance,

```
VAR := UnKnown
VAR_TERSE = $(call get_first_two_chars, $(VAR))

define get_first_two_char
...
endef
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it can be done, but it's pretty messy to implement by hand.  The easiest thing to do is to get the [GNU Make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sf.net), which has a built-in `substr` function.  If that's overkill, you can extract just that function from the library, but like I said, it's surprisingly messy.

Essentially you do a series of substitutions on the string to insert a space after each character:

```
EMPTY:=
SPACE:=$(EMPTY) $(EMPTY)
VAR := UnKnown
TMP:=$(subst a,a ,$(subst b,b ,$(subst c,c ,.........$(VAR)))))
# TMP now has "U n K n o w n"
```

Next you can use the `$(wordlist)` function to grab the first two "words" of the intermediate result:

```
TMP2:=$(wordlist 1,2,$(TMP))
# TMP2 now has "U n"
```

Finally, you use `$(subst)` again, now to strip out the space that you injected originally:

```
VAR_TERSE := $(subst $(SPACE),,$(TMP2))
# VAR_TERSE now has "Un"
```

Answer (score 2):

I really don't approve of forcing Make to do things it clearly doesn't want to do, but... I can't resist a good puzzle.

```
$(eval FOO := $$$(VAR))
$(eval FOO := $$$(FOO))
VAR_TERSE:= $(VAR:$(FOO)=)
```

Comment: Puzzling indeed. Any commentary?

Comment: Clever trick, but this will break, in really unpredictable ways, if you happen to have single-character variables that match the characters at the start of the original variable's value, or that match the characters at the start of _those_ variable's values.  For example, try adding "U:=XXX" at the start of your example makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Use the shell and sed?

```
define get_first_two_char
$(shell echo $1 | sed 's/^\(..\).*/\1/' )
endef
```